# Why does paint of one class does not see an array of another class?

Tags: java, swing, oop

So my problem is as follows: I am creating a clone of tetris. In one of my classes I have a Jpanel which draws everything and has a paint method.

```
public class Action extends JPanel { 
private final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.yellow; 

public Action() { 
    setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR); 
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 220)); 
    setVisible(true); 
    new Timer(1000, new TimerListener()).start(); 
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics pen) { 
    super.paintComponent(pen); 
    pen.setColor(Color.gray); 
    GameMemory memory = new GameMemory(); 
    int[][] grid = memory.getGrid(); 
    for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++ ) 
        for (int c = 0; c < grid[c].length; c++) 
            if (grid[r][c] == 1) 
                pen.fillRect(c * 30, r * 30, 40, 40); 
} 


private class TimerListener implements ActionListener { 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        Action.this.repaint(); 
    } 
} 

}
```

I was trying to make it repaint the every second.

The other class is an array that holds in memory occupied cells marking them with status 1 if they are.

```
/**
This class will contain a two-dimensional array that will 
keep in itself the figures, as well as checking if the raws are 
full.
```

*/

```
public class GameMemory { 
private final int AXIS_X = 6; //Where axis of the 
private final int AXIS_Y = 1; //figure will appear
private int curX = AXIS_X; 
private int curY = AXIS_Y; 
private final int[][] grid = new int[22][10]; 
FigureI figure = new FigureI(); 

GameMemory() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener()); 
    timer.start(); 
}


public int[][] getGrid() { 
    return grid; 
}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener { 
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        curY ++; 
        grid[curY + figure.block0[1]][curX + figure.block0[0]] = 1; 
        grid[curY + figure.block1[1]][curX + figure.block1[0]] = 1; 
        grid[curY + figure.block2[1]][curX + figure.block2[0]] = 1; 
        grid[curY + figure.block3[1]][curX + figure.block3[0]] = 1; 
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid)); // To debug.
    } 
}
```

And the third file simply contains figure coordinates.

```
  /**
    This file contains all the figures. 
    */ 



class FigureI { 

int[] block1 = { 0, -1 }; 
int[] block0 = { 0, 0 }; 
int[] block2 = { 0, 1 }; 
int[] block3 = { 0, 2 }; 

}


    class FigureJ { 
    int[] block1 = { 1, 0 }; 
    int[] block0 = { 0, 0 }; 
    int[] block2 = { -1, 0 }; 
    int[] block3 = { -1, -1 }; 
}

class FigureL { 
    int[] block1 = { -1, 0 }; 
    int[] block0 = { 0, 0 }; 
    int[] block2 = { 1, 0 }; 
    int[] block3 = { 1, 1 }; 
}

class FigureO { 
    int[] block1 = { 1, 0 }; 
    int[] block0 = { 0, 0 }; 
    int[] block2 = { -1, 0 }; 
    int[] block3 = { -1, 1 }; 
}

class FigureS { 
    int[] block1 = { -1, 0 }; 
    int[] block0 = { 0, 0 }; 
    int[] block2 = { 0, 1 }; 
    int[] block3 = { 1, 1 }; 
}

class FigureT { 
    int[] block1 = { 1, 0 }; 
    int[] block0 = { 0, 0 }; 
    int[] block2 = { -1, 0 }; 
    int[] block3 = { 0, 1 }; 
}

class FigureZ { 
    int[] block1 = { 1, 0 }; 
    int[] block0 = { 0, 0 }; 
    int[] block2 = { -1, 1 }; 
    int[] block3 = { 0, 1 }; 
}
```

### I have several questions regarding this in the order of importance:

1)How do I make a paint from the Action class recognize changes in the Game memory class over time?

2)When I put grid and figure variable into the Action class as well replacing the TimeListener from GameMemory to Action the figure does move indeed. What is the problem if I do it from another class then? 
I am trying to separate memory from painting because it seems logical to me. Is it possible?

3)I have a file with a whole bunch of package-private classes that contain relative figure coordinates. In the beginning I was trying to make it a public class that contains private inner classes, but I ran into a problem of instantiating inner private classes, and so I am thinking how to have a better design for my file with figures.

I am a complete noob in Java so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: To much of code. Can you limit your code, so that is makes readers life a bit easy.

Comment: Well, I guess you can just disregard code with figures and the third question then. With two first snippets it shouldn't be too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `GameMemory memory = new GameMemory()` in the paintComponent() method. Define the model separately and reuse it. Your render uses the model and just reflects the model state in the paintComponent() method.

In your TimerListener just update the model (move figures, clear rows etc.) and call the view's repaint() to reflect the model chnages.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. But I do not know what a model is. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html Is it the right link to look at? Can you suggest any good links that would explain me the concept in a compact manner? In my particular case, how would I separate the model? If I put new GameMemory() in the constructor it gives me a cannot find symbol error... I am still confused.

Comment: In your case the model is GameMemory. In fact you should have a class where the data of game are stored (grid with cell values, figures etc.). Imagine and create some data structure class containing lists (or arrays) of cells, figures with their positions, speed, scores etc. The model could be represented by some view, could be stored and loaded back, could be reset to restore initial values.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful, even though the terminology confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so using my highly limited brain capacity I was able to comprehend What StanislavL was talking about so I assumed that by term "model" he meant all the logic that was going on in the program.

So if I put the definition of the model into paintComponent method it will create an instance every time the timer is up in my case. Which is unnecessary. Instead, instantiate a model once, and repant it every timer is up. I guess I should also leave just one TimerTask as well (the one in the GameMemory) because super.paintComponent(pen) automaticaly repaints JPanel for me.

Overall here is the code I come up with and that works (still need to remove the timer):

```
public class Action extends JPanel { 
    private final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.yellow; 
    private GameMemory memory;
    private int[][] grid;

    public Action() { 
        memory = new GameMemory();
        grid = memory.getGrid();
        setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR); 
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 220)); 
        setVisible(true); 
        new Timer(1000, new TimerListener()).start(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics pen) { 
        super.paintComponent(pen); 
        pen.setColor(Color.gray); 
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++ ) 
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[c].length; c++) 
                if (grid[r][c] == 1) 
                    pen.fillRect(c * 30, r * 30, 40, 40); 
    } 


    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener { 
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            Action.this.repaint(); 
        } 
    } 

}
```